# Pandas KeyError: 'occurred at index 0'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a Pandas dataframe `df`:

```
start_time   Event
0            0
1            0
2            0
3            0
4            0
5            0
6            0
7            0
8            0
9            0
```

I want to set the value of the `Event` column to -1 when the corresponding `start_time` lies between two values, so I define this function:

```py
def test(time):
    if (time['start_time'] >= 5) and (time['start_time'] <= 8):
        return -1
    else:
        return time
```

To apply this to the event column, I do the following:

```py
df[['Event']] = df[['Event']].apply(test,axis=1)
```

which yields this error: `KeyError: ('start_time', 'occurred at index 0')`

Why is this happening? Should be a simple fix.

Comment: It should be `df.apply(test, axis=1)` not `df[['Event']].apply(test, axis=1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do:

```py
df['Event'] = df.apply(test, axis=1)['Event']
```

Comment: This is almost what I wanted but it also changes the values in the `start_time` column. I now see that the correct solution is: `df['Event'] = df.apply(test, axis=1)['Event']`

Comment: @blakebullwinkel I have edited my answer to include your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The function that you are passing to `.apply()` uses the `start_time` field of the input argument (in the conditional checks `if (time['start_time'] >= 5) and (time['start_time'] <= 8)`). So it should be applied to a DataFrame or Series that has a `start_time` column.

However, before you call apply you are first calling `df[['Event']]`, which returns a Series. So `df[['Event']].apply()` will apply a function to the resulting Series. But when the function reaches the expression `time['start_time']`, it is looking for a column called `start_time` in the Series, can't find it (because only 'Event' column was kept), and raises a KeyError.

The solution is to pass a DataFrame or a Series that has a `start_time` column in it. In your case you want to apply the function to the entire DataFrame so replace `df[['Event']]` with the whole DataFrame `df`.

```
df = df.apply(test, axis=1)
```

and change your function to modify the `Event` column instead of returning a value. Replace `return -1` with `time['Event'] = -1` and eliminate the `else return time` part (i.e., don't change anything if the conditions aren't met).